# Can command buttons in modeless forms be pressed? (Excel 2010/2016 VBA)

Tags: excel, userform, modeless

I have a VBA macro for Excel that may take a long time to process. In addition, in the beginning, I open another worksheet to get some data.  While this is happening, nothing appears to be going on on the screen.  I have a modeless userform that I want to display to indicate that processing is happening.

I'd like to put a command button on this userform that the user can click to stop the processing if they choose.  The problem is that when the userform is displayed, if I move the cursor over it, the cursor is an hourglass, and clicking on the button does nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Implement [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264522.aspx) into your macro to allow a user to press the `Cancel` button on your form. Alternatively, just state in your form that the user may [press Esc](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/interrupt-a-macro.html) at any time to halt the macro.

Comment: Unfortunately, Esc doesn't really work.  I put a code at the bottom of the data before starting processing so that I end processing if I hit that code.  I have accidentally told a routine to switch to a different column and wound up 30,000 rows down in a set of data that only had a few hundred rows.  Pressing Esc didn't work for me.  I usually had to End Task out of Excel.